# Using SwiftData outside of SwiftUI

Tags: swift-data, xcode15

I want to create a class for handling some data at regular intervals. I've not used CoreData. Outside of a SwiftUI view, how do I get the model container and context so I can retrieve and add objects? The code `let context = self.newSwiftContext(from: Trip.self)` shown in the WWDC video is not self-evident.

Answer (score 4):

Once you create the container

```
let configuration = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true, allowsSave: false)


let container = try ModelContainer(
    for: Trip.self, Accommodation.self, 
    configurations: configuration
)
```

You can access the context directly from the container.

```
let context = container.mainContext
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches

I would suggest making sure that the container is stored somewhere stable like in `UIApplicationDelegate`, a Singleton, a service that is preserved through the life of the app, etc.

Comment: One thing, `container.mainContext` is async so to get the context in a non async code you should do `let context = ModelContext(container)`

Comment: I did this because my app supports CoreLocation visits which could happen while the app is in the background and there's no SwiftUI View present. I store frequent places in SwiftData to augment information about the visit.

Comment: Link appears broken now

Comment: @Daniel I updated with the new one. Seems like Apple added dashes.